# how to execute something once when data fetched by SWR is available (useEffect)

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-hooks, swr

suppose I want to execute something once and only one time when `SWR` fetches the data and it's defined.

```
 const {
    data,
    isLoading,
    mutate,
 } = useSWR(`${process.env.BACKEND_BASE_URL}/resource`,fetcher);
```

usually, you would do this in a `useEffect` with no dependencies, but in this case, the data is `undefined`:

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log(data) // data is undefined here !!!
}, []);
```

Of course, if I add data to the dependency list, it will be executed when `data` turns into a defined value but then it will also be executed every time `data` changes in the future, which is not what I want.

I would appreciate any help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a Boolean ref to ensure that the `useEffect` is only executed once:

```
const effectCalledRef = useRef(false);

useEffect(() => {
  // check if data exists and the effect haven't been called
  if(data && !effectCalledRef .current) {
    console.log(data)
    effectCalledRef .current = true;
  }
}, [data]);
```